# Convert Isolated PDF File to HEX String in Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8.1, componentone

I am trying to Convert PDF File with image to HEX String, but do not know how to do it.

See my code below:

```
C1PdfDocument pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.A4);
pdf.Landscape = true;
var rc = new System.Windows.Rect();
pdf.DrawImage(wbitmp, rc);
var fillingName = txtTitle.Text + ".pdf";
var gettingFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var loadingFinalStream = gettingFile.CreateFile(fillingName))
{
   pdf.Save(loadingFinalStream);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StorageFolder sFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sFile = await sFolder.GetFileAsync("PDF.pdf");
var sFileOut = await sFile.OpenReadAsync();
Stream sFileOutStream = sFileOut.AsStream();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
await sFileOutStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
byte[] sFileOutStreamByte = ms.ToArray();
string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(sFileOutStreamByte);
```

Hope this helps... ;-)

Comment: Ok man, I shall test it. Thank you very much brother!! @Vincenzo

Comment: @NiteshKothari you're welcome, if you want mark as answer ;-)